flex container not working inside tab content page
I am creating a site with tabs using style element of tab and tab content.
In one of the tabs content, i want to use a flex container to control display of various elements - tables, graphs and text.
On a standalone page without the tab, it works fine but when i am trying to use it in the main page within the tabs content, it is stacking up the divs one above the other.
My style.css file is as below:
// style file for use in all the php files for this site

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}


}

I am using Chart.js to create graphs and using php javascript for data handling.
What am i doing incorrectly?
The html file which is not working is as below


<?php
// Database connection details
require_once 'dbconn.php';
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
      // Declare all variables
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

      // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }

      // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }

      // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
    </script>

</head>


<h2>Waterfront Trident

<br>

</h2>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Monthly')">Current Month</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Historical')">History</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Alarms')">Alarms</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Trends')">Trends</button>
</div>

<div id="Trends" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="flex-container">

      <div>
                <?php

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM pilot_efficiency where Sitename = 'Hercules Tower'";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        echo "<table>";

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<th> EFFICIENCY </td>";
                        echo "<th> PILOT CHILLER </td>";
                        echo "</tr>";

                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Month'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" .  $row['PilotEffy'] ." KWH/ton</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";

                    }
                        echo "</table>";
                        echo "</td>";

                        echo "<td>";
                        echo "<table>";


                        echo "</table>";                

                } else {
                    echo "no data to display";
                }

            ?>

      </div>
        <div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <?php
    // Database connection details
    

    $sql = "SELECT Month, PilotEffy FROM pilot_efficiency where Sitename = 'Hercules Tower'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($mth, $piloteffy);

    $mth_array = Array();
    $effy_array = Array();


    while($stmt->fetch()) {
            $mth_array[] = $mth;
            $effy_array[] = $piloteffy;
    }

    $mth_array = json_encode($mth_array);
    $effy_array = json_encode($effy_array);

    ?>

    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

    <script>
      var mtharray = <?php echo $mth_array; ?>;
      var effyarray = <?php echo $effy_array; ?>;

      if (!Array.isArray(mtharray) || !mtharray.length) {
               var text = 'array not populated';
               document.getElementById('jserror').innerHTML=text;
        } else {

        }


      const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

      new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: mtharray,
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Pilot Efficiency Monthly',
            data: effyarray,
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        }
      });
    </script>

  </div>
  <div>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT sum(Cool_Upgr) as Cool_Upgr, sum(Cool_Pilot) as Cool_Pilot, sum(Power_Upgr) as Power_Upgr, sum(Power_Pilot) as Power_Pilot, sum(Power_Pumps) as Power_Pumps FROM gl_caas_mtd where Sitename = 'Hercules Tower'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<caption> CUMMULATIVE PLANT SUMMARY</caption>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> Cooling </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Cool_Upgr'] + $row['Cool_Pilot'] . " Tons</td>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> Power </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Power_Upgr'] + $row['Power_Pilot'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] . " KWh</td>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> Efficiency Gain </td>";
                echo "<td>" . round((1 - round(($row['Power_Upgr'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3) / $row['Cool_Upgr'],2) / round(($row['Power_Pilot'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3 * 2) / $row['Cool_Pilot'],2)) * 100, 0) . "%" . "</td>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "</table>";
                
              }
            } else {
                echo "No data to display";
            }

        ?>

  </div>
  <div>
    <?php

      $sql = "SELECT sum(Cool_Upgr) as Cool_Upgr, sum(Cool_Pilot) as Cool_Pilot, sum(Power_Upgr) as Power_Upgr, sum(Power_Pilot) as Power_Pilot, sum(Power_Pumps) as Power_Pumps FROM gl_caas_mtd where Sitename = 'Hercules Tower'";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      echo "<table>";
      echo "<caption> MONTHLY SAVINGS </caption>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>KWh</td>";
      echo "<td>" . round((round(($row['Power_Pilot'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3 * 2) / $row['Cool_Pilot'],2) - round(($row['Power_Upgr'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3) / $row['Cool_Upgr'],2)) * $row['Cool_Upgr'], 0) . " KWh</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>KWh</td>";
      echo "<td>" . round((round(($row['Power_Pilot'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3 * 2) / $row['Cool_Pilot'],2) - round(($row['Power_Upgr'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3) / $row['Cool_Upgr'],2)) * $row['Cool_Upgr'] * 0.47, 0) . " Tons</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>KWh</td>";
      echo "<td>" . round((round(($row['Power_Pilot'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3 * 2) / $row['Cool_Pilot'],2) - round(($row['Power_Upgr'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3) / $row['Cool_Upgr'],2)) * $row['Cool_Upgr'] * 0.44, 0) . " AED</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</table>";
    }
  }
    ?>
  </div>
</div>


</html>



The same code works fine when in a standalone file.


<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}

</style>
<html>
<?php require_once 'dbconn.php'; ?>

<head>

</head>

<div class="flex-container">

  <div>
            <?php

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM pilot_efficiency where Sitename = 'Hercules Tower'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "<table>";

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th> EFFICIENCY </td>";
                    echo "<th> PILOT CHILLER </td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['Month'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" .  $row['PilotEffy'] ." KWH/ton</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

                }
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo "</td>";

                    echo "<td>";
                    echo "<table>";


                    echo "</table>";                

            } else {
                echo "no data to display";
            }

        ?>

  </div>
    <div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <?php
    // Database connection details
    

    $sql = "SELECT Month, PilotEffy FROM pilot_efficiency where Sitename = 'Hercules Tower'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($mth, $piloteffy);

    $mth_array = Array();
    $effy_array = Array();


    while($stmt->fetch()) {
            $mth_array[] = $mth;
            $effy_array[] = $piloteffy;
    }

    $mth_array = json_encode($mth_array);
    $effy_array = json_encode($effy_array);

    ?>

    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

    <script>
      var mtharray = <?php echo $mth_array; ?>;
      var effyarray = <?php echo $effy_array; ?>;

      if (!Array.isArray(mtharray) || !mtharray.length) {
               var text = 'array not populated';
               document.getElementById('jserror').innerHTML=text;
        } else {

        }


      const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

      new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: mtharray,
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Pilot Efficiency Monthly',
            data: effyarray,
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        }
      });
    </script>

  </div>
  <div>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT sum(Cool_Upgr) as Cool_Upgr, sum(Cool_Pilot) as Cool_Pilot, sum(Power_Upgr) as Power_Upgr, sum(Power_Pilot) as Power_Pilot, sum(Power_Pumps) as Power_Pumps FROM gl_caas_mtd where Sitename = 'Hercules Tower'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<caption> CUMMULATIVE PLANT SUMMARY</caption>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> Cooling </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Cool_Upgr'] + $row['Cool_Pilot'] . " Tons</td>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> Power </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Power_Upgr'] + $row['Power_Pilot'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] . " KWh</td>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> Efficiency Gain </td>";
                echo "<td>" . round((1 - round(($row['Power_Upgr'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3) / $row['Cool_Upgr'],2) / round(($row['Power_Pilot'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3 * 2) / $row['Cool_Pilot'],2)) * 100, 0) . "%" . "</td>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "</table>";
                
              }
            } else {
                echo "No data to display";
            }

        ?>

  </div>
  <div>
    <?php

      $sql = "SELECT sum(Cool_Upgr) as Cool_Upgr, sum(Cool_Pilot) as Cool_Pilot, sum(Power_Upgr) as Power_Upgr, sum(Power_Pilot) as Power_Pilot, sum(Power_Pumps) as Power_Pumps FROM gl_caas_mtd where Sitename = 'Hercules Tower'";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      echo "<table>";
      echo "<caption> MONTHLY SAVINGS </caption>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>KWh</td>";
      echo "<td>" . round((round(($row['Power_Pilot'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3 * 2) / $row['Cool_Pilot'],2) - round(($row['Power_Upgr'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3) / $row['Cool_Upgr'],2)) * $row['Cool_Upgr'], 0) . " KWh</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>KWh</td>";
      echo "<td>" . round((round(($row['Power_Pilot'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3 * 2) / $row['Cool_Pilot'],2) - round(($row['Power_Upgr'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3) / $row['Cool_Upgr'],2)) * $row['Cool_Upgr'] * 0.47, 0) . " Tons</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>KWh</td>";
      echo "<td>" . round((round(($row['Power_Pilot'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3 * 2) / $row['Cool_Pilot'],2) - round(($row['Power_Upgr'] + $row['Power_Pumps'] / 3) / $row['Cool_Upgr'],2)) * $row['Cool_Upgr'] * 0.44, 0) . " AED</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</table>";
    }
  }
    ?>
  </div>
</div>


</html>



resulting in a great layout like


Provide html too and all necessary code.

Have you used your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what HTML is being generated and exactly what CSS is being applied to it? We need to see the generated HTML (not as an image but as code in your question).

It worked after putting flex container after tab.
